# I need to find the repeating characters in 2 strings

Tags: c

I'm trying to find the repeating elements in the 2 strings. Here is what I have done.

```
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    char S[5];
    char J[4];
    printf("Enter the 1st string\n");
    scanf("%s", &S);
    printf("\nEnter the 2nd string\n");
    scanf("%s",&J);
    printf("\n1st string characters are %s", &S);
    printf("\n2nd string characters are %s", &J);


    for(i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<3; j++)
        {

        if(J[j] == S[i])
        {
            printf("\n\nThe element is found and is at %c", *(&S[i]));
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nNo matching element found");
            break;
        }
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

The output im getting is

Enter the 1st string
asdf

Enter the 2nd string
cfv

1st string characters are asdf
2nd string characters are cfv

```
The element is found and is at
No matching element found
No matching element found
No matching element found
No matching element found
No matching element found
```

Any idea why this might be happening? I'm a rookie in this. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Code is always `break;` after `j=0`.  It does not get to `j=1`.  Try it without any `break` to gain insight.

Answer (score 3):

i can make a few suggestions in your loop replace i<5 and j<3 to `i<strlen(S)` similarly     `j<strlen(J)` 
strlen is used to calculate string length. 
and do not use break; otherwise it will skip the loop at first match . so try this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
 int i, j;
char S[]="rat";
char J[]="fat";


printf("\n1st string characters are %s", &S);
printf("\n2nd string characters are %s", &J);


for(i=0; S[i] != '\0';; i++)
{
    for (j=0; J[j] != '\0';; j++)
    {

    if(J[j] == S[i])
    {
        printf("\n\nThe element is found and is at %c", *(&S[i]));

    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nNo matching element found");

    }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

**[click here to see the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VC8qO.png)The output is shown in a image.**
sorry i was not having a c compiler in my system so used online one and may be thats why the location is not shown but yes it resolves your problem the matches are being detected.

Comment: I want to get the input string from the user and then need to check for it. One more thing. Can u tell me what have you done after i=0 and j=0 in both the loops? S[i] != '\0' what does this do?

Comment: Nit, double `;;` in loop definitions. Just a typo. `*(&S[i])` the use of `'*'` and `'&'` together is superfluous, the derefernce negates the address of resulting in simply `S[i]`.

Comment: @ChinmayKhole '\0' is string end character .